# Nginx reverse proxy to web app in kubernetes gives 404 for static web resources

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi nginx extraordinaire's

I am using nginx as a load balancer and reverse proxy to play the role of an external-facing API gateway to interface applications and api's hosted in kubernetes. these are all exposed via ingress

[image]

The issue I am facing is that nginx is giving me 404s when I try to access a standard angular web app via the **/test** URL

See error:

[image]

Nginx was set up using the following config - **nginx.conf**

```
    events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

ssl                       on;
ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhostname/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhostname/privkey.pem;

client_max_body_size      1G;

upstream k8snodes {
  server 192.168.2.10; 
  server 192.168.2.11;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;

    location / {
      proxy_pass            http://k8snodes/;
      proxy_redirect        off;
      proxy_set_header      Host $host;
      proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 }

 }
```

Sitting behind **/test** is a Kubernetes ingress controller that serves the angular application. I can confirm that application can be accessed fine when directly through ingress so there is something that nginx is not happy with.

Ingress config

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-09-14T07:43:49Z"
  generation: 2
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "12193067"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/test- 
ingress
  uid: f8c5ea11-9caf-431e-9a18-19bd3981eece
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhostname
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

Is there something I have done wrong on the Nginx config? I have other API's that are reverse proxied fine it seems to be the web applications that try to serve **static files** that are giving issues.

Comment: What is the complete path where it's trying to access the files?

Comment: Request URL: https://mydomainname/styles.09e2c710755c8867a460.css

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 404 Not Found


Remote Address: xxxxxxxx:443

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade `

it seems the /test is not in the path

Comment: And where are the files? mydomainname/test/css/ and mydomainname/test/js/ or similar? Are you using relative or absolute paths in your html?

Comment: The files are supposed to be accessible from the root as the index.html file that loads when I access /test location has the following - <script src="runtime-es2015.b2aca5be9e7b8cc1a1b4.js" type="module"></script>

Comment: Accessing https://mydomainname/test/styles.09e2c710755c8867a460.css with the **/test** does not load the file either and seems to attempt to route back to the /

Comment: What about something like `location /(.*)$ {...proxy_pass     http://k8snodes/$1;...}`?

Comment: You could also try adding `location /test/ {}` inside the `location / {}` directive but you may need to specify the root path. It's tricky because of the reverse proxy.

Comment: @Keith, did you try advise form EternalHour ?

Comment: So because the angular application used nginx aswell it wasn't serving the static files at the root / the second nginx being the gateway was trying to access the static files from this server via the root path. What i did is made sure the nginx files were served from /test aswell. I am now having further issues serving the application through the gateway but atleast the static files have served. Thanks @EternalHour